# How to properly configure snmpd?

Tags: centos, snmp

I installed `snmp` on CentOS `7.2`, like so:

```
yum -y install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
```

I made a backup of my `snmpd.conf` file:

```
cp /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf.orig
```

then I cleared the text, with this:

```
echo "" > /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
```

and added to the `snmpd.conf`, the following:

> `rocommunity "#random$" monitoring_server_ip`

The `monitoring_server_ip` is the server that that is allowed to connect to this snmpd server.

Restarted snmpd

```
/bin/systemctl restart snmpd
```

When I run snmpwalk on my CentOS `7.2` server

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost system
```

I then get:

> Timeout: No Response from localhost

Which is accurate, because there is only one IP-adres that can do that, as we have defined before.

`ps` shows that `snmp` is running

> `/usr/sbin/snmpd -LS0-6d -f`

This is my first time playing with `snmp` and any help is greatly appreciated!

output of `iptables -L -n | grep udp` shows this:

```
...
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
   94  target     prot opt source               destination
   95  ACCEPT     udp  --  XX.XXX.XXX.XXX        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:161 ctstate NEW
...
```

All of the destination was too `0.0.0.0/0`?

Netstat shows the following port:

```
 netstat -ulnp | grep 161
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*                           19062/snmpd
```

also this:

```
netstat -lu | grep snmp
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:snmp            0.0.0.0:*
```

Also, in my firewall, added that only one IP-adres can access my snmp server:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule="rule family="ipv4" source address="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" port protocol="udp" port="161" accept"
```

Comment: Edited my Q a lil bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The com2sec security model is not mandatory anymore.

In `snmpd.conf` it should be enough to do:

```
rocommunity "#randomsometinh$"  2.2.2.2
```

where 2.2.2.2 is the monitoring IP address allowed to connect.
I often prefer to assign a single IP, than giving access to a whole /24. So this configuration means the SNMP service will answer requests from the 2.2.2.2 address.

You might also have to comment the line that restricts the snmpd daemon to the localhost for security reasons.

```
# agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
```

After changing the configuration file, do:

```
service restart snmpd
```

To confirm if it is listening locally:

```
$ netstat -lu | grep snmp
udp        0      0 *:snmp                  *:*
```

And from the allowed network/IP, for walking the entire MIB tree. Assuming 2.2.2.1 is the machine being monitored:

```
snmpwalk -c "#randomsometinh$" -v2c 2.2.2.1
```

or for asking for the [sysUpTime OID](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3):

```
snmpwalk -c "#randomsometinh$" -v2c 2.2.2.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3
snmpget -c #randomsometinh$ -v2c 2.2.2.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
```

snmpget has to have the 0 for the specific object instance/index.

P.S: 2.2.2.2 is the monitoring server, and 2.2.2.1 is the snmpd server/host to be monitored.

Comment: HoI! Sorry for the late reply! But I can't find the `agentAddress  ` in `snmpd.conf`. Its not there: `cat /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf | grep agentAddress` This displays nothing!

Comment: Which it is not necessarily bad. It was added by some distributions as an additional step of security. Adding the rocommunity are you able to use it?

Comment: When I use the `snmpwalk` command, I get an output that's `5821` lines. I have no idea if that's a good thing!

Comment: Yes, snmpwak is supposed to walk the MIB tree without additional arguments...you can try getting a specific OID or using `snmpget`. So it is working.

Comment: I replaced the `nmpwalk` with `snmpget`, but I then get: `Missing object name`!

Comment: Okay, I know that OID is an `Object identifier`, and that site you linked at, I'm not sure what to do with that?

Comment: It is just to justify where 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3 comes from. I updated the answer with the commands.

Comment: Okay, I get the following after that: `DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (370395) 1:01:43.95`

Comment: So it is working, that is the machine uptime-.

Comment: Awesome! Just one thing that needs to get done. I need to only allow one IP-adress, to connect to the snmp server! I need to add this: `agentAddress  udp:**allowed_ip-adress**`, right?

Comment: On my `snmpd.conf` the `2.2.2.2` part is where I had put the server IP adres where snmp is installed on. `rocommunity #randomsometinh$  IP-adres_of_snmp_server`. So, I edit that, replace the curent snmp server IP-adres, with the IP-adres of the machine, that is going to connect to the SNMP server?

Comment: Edited it again the post for clarity.

Comment: `Timeout: No Response from ...` the monitoring server or the snmp server:  `2.2.2.2`/`2.2.2.1`?

Comment: on snmpd.conf after the rocommunity is the IP of the monitoring server.

Comment: `rocommunity #snmp2016ABC$ monitoring_ip_adres`

Comment: yes, the IP address of the server where you run snmget/walk

Comment: The iP-adres of the server where snmp is installed, is what I use to run snmget, and also the ip of the guy that is gonna monitor that server, and both IP adresses I get: `Timeout: No Response from ...` internal and an external IP?

Comment: Could it that the ip-adres in the snmpd conf file, is the only ip-adres that can now test it?

Comment: My `snmpd.conf` is has nothing else in it

Comment: exactly. As soon you put there the address *and restart the service* you will be only able to test *from that IP address* as the configuration means "I will only answer requests coming from that IP address*

Comment: Thanks! Than I'll wait their reply, to see if everything is working properly.

Comment: Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Unfortunately they can't seem to connect to the snmp server. I also - with the `firewall` command - made a rule to disallow, every ip's connection to `udp` port  `161`. Other then that, Its the same. Like so: http://serverfault.com/a/684603/114962

Comment: How about the corporate firewall? Please display the output of `netstat -lu | grep snmp`

Comment: `udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:snmp            0.0.0.0:*`

Comment: It is listening indeed. What about tests of your network team? Add to the post `iptables -L -n` please

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: only state NEW in iptables is not enough, unless you have something else on iptables...try to test it out with no states first

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: would you give me the relevant iptables rule? How did you create it?

Comment: I'll edit my question whit everything I've done so far

Comment: I have Edited my Q

Comment: all seems ok.... add another line rocommunity  with an IP address you control....for testing.

Comment: My apologize. It was users error. they got it to work. Also, I read in a doc, that every special character, should be in single quotes in de snmpd.conf `'#randomsometinh$'`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The ' part makes some sense. I try to avoid using special characters as to avoid potential problems with some device. Good to know everything is working. cheers.