# SNMP - No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

Tags: linux, centos, snmp

I installed a snmpd into a CentOS 7 minimal installation for system parameters search, for instance:

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
```

for the above command I get the following result:

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

when i execute:

```
 snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1
```

to check if the IF-MIB is loaded by snmpd, i get the following result:

```
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux vm_test.whatever.com 3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 26 16:32:21 UTC 2018 x86_64
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpAgentOIDs.10
     DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (90641) 0:15:06.41
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmp.local.conf)
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: vm_test.whatever.com
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: Unknown (edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf)
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.1 = OID: SNMP-MPD-MIB::snmpMPDCompliance
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.2 = OID: SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmMIBCompliance
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.3 = OID: SNMP-FRAMEWORK- MIB::snmpFrameworkMIBCompliance
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.4 = OID: SNMPv2-MIB::snmpMIB
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.5 = OID: TCP-MIB::tcpMIB
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.6 = OID: IP-MIB::ip
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.7 = OID: UDP-MIB::udpMIB
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.8 = OID: SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB::vacmBasicGroup
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.9 = OID: SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB::snmpNotifyFullCompliance
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.10 = OID: NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB::notificationLogMIB
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.1 = STRING: The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching.
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.2 = STRING: The management information definitions for the SNMP User-based Security Model.
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.3 = STRING: The SNMP Management Architecture MIB.
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.4 = STRING: The MIB module for SNMPv2 entities
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.5 = STRING: The MIB module for managing TCP implementations
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.6 = STRING: The MIB module for managing IP and ICMP implementations
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.7 = STRING: The MIB module for managing UDP implementations
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.8 = STRING: View-based Access Control Model for SNMP.
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.9 = STRING: The MIB modules for managing SNMP Notification, plus filtering.
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.10 = STRING: The MIB module for logging SNMP Notifications.
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.1 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.2 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.3 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.4 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.5 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.6 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.7 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.8 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.9 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.10 = Timeticks: (4) 0:00:00.04
     HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = Timeticks: (872972) 2:25:29.72
     HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

the output tells me that IF-MIB is not being checked, but if execute the command:

```
 snmptranslate -Dinit_mib .1.3.2>&1 | grep MIBDIR
```

to check the mibdirs (directories) and MIB's found (Seen MIBS) i get the following result:

```
  registered debug token init_mib, 1
  init_mib: Seen MIBDIRS: Looking in '/root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs' for mib dirs ...
  init_mib: Seen MIBS: Looking in ':HOST-RESOURCES-MIB:HOST-RESOURCES- 
  TYPES:UCD-DISKIO-MIB:TCP-MIB:UDP-MIB:MTA-MIB:NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB:SCTP- 
  MIB:RMON-MIB:EtherLike-MIB:LM-SENSORS-MIB:SNMPv2-MIB:IF-MIB:IP- 
  MIB:NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB:DISMAN-EVENT-MIB:DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB:UCD-SNMP- 
  MIB:UCD-DEMO-MIB:SNMP-TARGET-MIB:NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB:SNMP-MPD-MIB:SNMP- 
  USER-BASED-SM-MIB:SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB:SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB:SNMP- 
  COMMUNITY-MIB:IPV6-ICMP-MIB:IPV6-MIB:IPV6-TCP-MIB:IPV6-UDP-MIB:IP-FORWARD- 
  MIB:NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB:NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB:UCD-DLMOD-MIB:SNMP-NOTIFICATION- 
  MIB:SNMPv2-TM:NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB' for mib files ...
  init_mib: Seen PREFIX: Looking in '.1.3.6.1.2.1' for prefix ..
```

and if you look carefully, the IF-MIB is there tagged as Seen Mibs. Why is it not showing up in the snmpwalk command? and why does the OID related to the IF-MIB doesn't exist in this agent? is this something permission related? OS related?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SNMP daemon upon installation in CentOS is configured by default to answer to queries of a restricted MIB tree view using the "public" community for security reasons.

As configured by default, the default "public" MIB (sub)tree allowed views are only .1.3.6.1.2.1.1 and .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1 ; if you look closely the IF-MIB address space is  .1.3.6.1.2.1.2. So querying objects on that MIB address space is not allowed by default. It also explains why that `snmpwalk` command of yours shows only a very restricted view.

Consequently, to get the SNMP daemon/service answering to your queries, you have firstly to configure a new view (and for security reasons better also a new community) on the configuration file `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`.

We shall then configure a "private" community for security reasons, and widen the MIB tree space which can be queried.

As such, add to `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`

```
rocommunity private 127.0.0.1 .1
```

Where 127.0.0.1 is the IP address which can make queries, and .1 the whole MIB tree. *ro*community also certifies you can only make read queries, which are more secure.

After configuring the `snmpd.conf` file, you have to restart the SNMP service, as in:

```
sudo service snmpd restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart snmpd
```

Now for the query. If you are not asking for a MIB leaf node, you cannot use `snmpget`. You have to use `snmpwalk` for it to walk the MIB tree as in:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c private 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: lo
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: eth0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: eth1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.4 = STRING: eth2
```

On the other hand, if you need to query a leaf node of the MIB tree, for instance, your second interface in the system, you do:

```
$ snmpget -v 2c -c private 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: eth0
```

PS Obviously in production systems, you call your community name something other than private.

PS2. The fact that you install a MIB file, is that you are installing dictionaries that translate numbers to readable text for humans and scripts/network monitoring software alike. Not having a MIB installed does not prevent from querying a specific MIB subtree in numeric form *if the security context for accessing that SNMP community allows it*

Comment: It worked, thanks alot for the detailed explanation, it really makes a difference in the learning process. =]

Comment: You are welcome. See also, related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268959/how-to-properly-configure-snmpd/268962#268962

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to snmpwalk,

```
snmpwalk  -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
```

will give you the result as below

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: lo
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: eth2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: eth3
IF-MIB::ifDescr.4 = STRING: eth4
IF-MIB::ifDescr.5 = STRING: eth5
IF-MIB::ifDescr.6 = STRING: eth0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.7 = STRING: eth1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.8 = STRING: eth6
IF-MIB::ifDescr.9 = STRING: eth7
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10 = STRING: bond0
```

So you should add another node to get the result.

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1
```

Comment: It seems that subtree view is not included by default in snmpd.conf for the public community queries in CentOS. The default "public" MIB tree views are `.1.3.6.1.2.1.1`  and `.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1`