# Keepalived SNMP not working

Tags: rhel, snmp

Im configuring Keepalived in a RHEL 7.
It working correctly all by snmp.

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cpublic 10.18.0.8 KEEPALIVED-MIB::vrrpInstanceTable

KEEPALIVED-MIB::vrrpInstanceTable = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

Keepalived version and build options

```
Keepalived v1.3.5 (03/19,2017), git commit v1.3.5-6-g6fa32f2
Build options:  PIPE2 LIBNL3 RTA_ENCAP RTA_EXPIRES RTA_PREF FRA_OIFNAME FRA_TUN_ID RTAX_CC_ALGO RTAX_QUICKACK LIBIPTC LIBIPSET_DYNAMIC LVS LIBIPVS_NETLINK VRRP VRRP_AUTH VRRP_VMAC SOCK_NONBLOCK SOCK_CLOEXEC FIB_ROUTING INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE SNMP_V3_FOR_V2 SNMP SNMP_KEEPALIVED SNMP_CHECKER SNMP_RFC SNMP_RFCV2 SNMP_RFCV3 SO_MARK
```

Snmp version

```
NET-SNMP version:  5.7.2
```

Keepalived logs:

```
Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Starting SNMP subagent
NET-SNMP version 5.7.2 AgentX subagent connected
VRRP_Instance(VI) removing protocol VIPs.
Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(2), proto(112), unicast(1), fd(15,16)]
VRRP_Script(check_process) succeeded
VRRP_Instance(VI) Transition to MASTER STATE
VRRP_Instance(VI) Received advert with higher priority 109, ours 100
VRRP_Instance(VI) Entering BACKUP STATE
VRRP_Instance(VI): Sending SNMP notification
VRRP_Instance(VI) Changing effective priority from 100 to 110
```

/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf - Added the following

```
master agentx
agentXSocket /var/agentx/master
```

/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf (global_defs section with...)

```
        enable_snmp_keepalived       # enable SNMP handling of vrrp element of KEEPALIVED MIB
        enable_snmp_checker          # enable SNMP handling of checker element of KEEPALIVED MIB
        enable_snmp_rfc              # enable SNMP handling of RFC2787 and RFC6527 VRRP MIBs
        enable_snmp_rfcv2            # enable SNMP handling of RFC2787 VRRP MIB
        enable_snmp_rfcv3            # enable SNMP handling of RFC6527 VRRP MIB
        enable_traps                 # enable SNMP traps
```

I've been browsing throush several articles but no sucess.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Debian 10 Buster, finally found the answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464030

Apparently out of the box snmpd is configured to only allow access to these subtrees:

```
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
```

You can fix it in multiple ways by modifying the view e.g. adding

`view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.9586`

or adding another community that isn't restricted etc.